Qt signals and slots: simplified connect syntax?
The Qt documentation gives the following example for connecting a signal to a slot:
QObject::connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, label, &QLabel::setText);

However, the syntax is somewhat complicated (that is, verbose) and can be shortened by using this macro:
#define CONNECT(sender, signal, receiver, method) \
    QObject::connect( \
        sender,   &std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(sender)>::signal, \
        receiver, &std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(receiver)>::method \
    )

Now, the above connection simplifies to:
CONNECT(lineEdit, textChanged, label, setText);

I've tested this and it works fine. So, it seems that this macro allows to combine the advantages of the functor-based connection syntax (compile-time type checking and implicit type conversions) with an easy syntax. Granted, it won't work for overloaded signals or slots, or when the connection type should not be the default Qt::AutoConnection.
My question is: Are there any issues with this approach which I'm not yet aware of, and is it actually a good idea at all?

The "new syntax" was meant to get rid of using macros and the associated drawbacks, so coming back to a macro feels weird... Moreover, I disagree that the syntax is "complicated", this is pure C++, you just provide addresses to member functions, this is not even Qt-related. And it is way more readable and explicit than  using a macro because you need to see the macro definition to know what it does while with the normal syntax, well... it's just plain C++, you do not need to go elsewhere to understand what it means.

not sure if this makes sense in Qt, but generally speaking funciton poitners allow you to do something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/qKofar96j. Even if you dont want to use such a hack, the original Qt version is explicit about what function pointer is actually used, your shorter version is not. Usually hiding information is not "simpler" on the long term. Consider that code is read much more often that it is read, so any character you safe on typing has to be paid back many times later

Using a lambda for the slot method is another thing that's out.

Answering my own question, I'm now using a modified approach of this and found it to be working well. (Note that this solution needs a compiler with __VA_OPT__ support, so either a C++20 or GNU compiler.)
#define MEMBER(object, member, ...) object, __VA_OPT__(qOverload<__VA_ARGS__>)(&std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(object)>::member)
#define SENDER(object, signal, ...) MEMBER(object, signal, __VA_ARGS__)
#define RECEIVER(object, method, ...) MEMBER(object, method, __VA_ARGS__)

Now, the following three example connections
connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, label, &QLabel::setText);

connect(
    spinbox, qOverload<int>(&QSpinBox::valueChanged),
    lcdNumber, qOverload<int>(&QLCDNumber::display)
);

connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::connected, [=] () { /* ... */ });

simplify to this:
connect(SENDER(lineEdit, textChanged), RECEIVER(label, setText));
connect(SENDER(spinbox, valueChanged, int), RECEIVER(lcdNumber, display, int));
connect(SENDER(socket, connected), [=] () { /* ... */ });

I think that this approach has some advantages:

All benefits of the functor-based connection syntax like compile-time type checking and implicit type conversions are still fully supported.
It's not necessary to explicitly state the class name of the sender and receiver objects. The compiler already has this information anyway, and explicitly connecting to an overridden base implementation of a virtual slot should (almost?) never be necessary. Also, the variable  itself should have a clean name anyway. So why should I bother to restate the class name?
Code snippets like SENDER(lineEdit, textChanged) are perfectly understandable even if the macro definition isn't looked up by the reader.
It's easy to use overloaded signals and slots. Simply state the desired function signature within the SENDER and RECEIVER macros. For example, SENDER(spinbox, valueChanged, int) will connect to the QSpinBox::valueChanged(int) overload.
It's possible to connect to lambda functions, as shown in the example above.
It's possible to create connections of all supported connection types.

